# Correct explanation how engine scan the given string using greedy regexes (DFA, NFA)

Tags: regex, string, regex-greedy, dfa, nfa

I parse step by step **/\w+s/** and **/\w*s/** regexes for "**We take illiterate questions**" string
for Regex-Directed Engine (NFA) and Text-Directed Engine (DFA).

I've been looking correct explanation for the last three weeks.
My teacher gave me the following explanation how the engine parse this string. Is that right (for NFA)?

**/\w+s/ 

"We take illiterate questions"**

> The engine starts at the beginning, and it says, I have got a W { in
>   "We"}. That's a word character. That works fine.
>
> The engine goes to the e - it's still a word character.
>
> The engine is greedy, so it's still trying to consume each of these
>   things in that first expression, the word character.
>
> Then it gets to the space, and it says okay, that's not a word
>   character and that's not an s, so it fails both tests; therefore this
>   didn't work out.
>
> At that point it backtracks to the e. Then it says, let's try this
>   possibility: what if this is the first expression?
>
> That first expression matches - it's a word character - so then it
>   goes to the s. Still it's no s.
>
> So now it looks again, and it says, all right, the space is neither a
>   word character or an s, so then it moves to the t. {in "take"}
>
> It tries the t. It says, that's a word character, the a is a word, the
>   k and the e. When it finally gets to the space, it says, this is not a
>   word character.
>
> Now let's move to the second part of the expression, that's the s,
>   it's not an s either.
>
> Now we backtrack to the a. {in "take"} We tried the t, so now we
>   backtrack to the a. Now we try again.
>
> And the engine moves along the first part of the expression till it
>   gets to the space, and it says this is not a word character, then
>   checks and says, it's not an s either, so now it backtracks back to
>   the k. {in "take"}
>
> It starts the same thing over there again, till it gets to the space,
>   and then it backtracks to the e, and so on.
>
> Then when it gets to the e {in "illiteratE"} and to the space, it
>   realizes that that didn't work out and then it works its way to the q
>   {in "questions"}, and of course it moves its way along the a until it
>   gets to the s, which works, and we have a match.

**/\w*s/

"We take illiterate questions"**

> Let's go ahead and just forward to the work illiterate.
>
> The star is also greedy by default, so it's going to want to consume
>   as many word characters as it can. So it's going to start out and it's
>   going to do the exact same thing that the previous version did.
>
> But here's the difference.
>
> It gets to the last character and says, okay, this is not a word
>   character and it's not an s.
>
> This time it backtracks to the i {in "illiterate"} because there is a
>   second possibility for the asterisk, which is the possibility that it
>   didn't match anything.
>
> What if this i {in "illiterate"} was not anything? What if instead I
>   take the lazy strategy and have it be zero and then check the next
>   character and see if that would be a s?
>
> It's not, so it failed.
>
> So now it doesn't need to backtrack. It's tried both its strategies on
>   i {in "illiterate"}: it's tried the greedy strategy and the lazy
>   strategy.
>
> Now it says, all right, let's start with l {in "iLliterate"}.
>
> Is l a word character?
>
> Yes it is. It moves its way along and goes back and pretty much works
>   the same way that the plus did.
>
> But, it pops back to the first l {in "iLliterate"} this time instead
>   of the second l {in "ilLiterate"}. So it goes back one character
>   further, because it has the second possibility, a possibility that it
>   didn't match anything. And so on.

Thanks.

Comment: `It's tried the greedy strategy and the lazy strategy.` For NFA, the engine doesn't switch between greedy and lazy - it is already specified by the pattern. The only difference between the 2 cases is that, `\w*` can match empty string, which is the last case that it tries, after trying n, n-1, ..., 2, 1 repetitions of `\w`.

Comment: I care 
> At that point it backtracks to the e. Then it says, let's try this possibility: **what if this is the first expression?** 

I thought the engine backtracks to check for 'e' matches /s/. But in this text the engine backtracks to the 'e' and compares 'e' with /w+/.

I think it's error.

Comment: There seems to be a missing step: after we(no s), it should check for w(no s) before advance the index and check for e(no s).

Comment: Thanks. It's missed for NFA. And how the engine will parse in DFA mode?

Comment: In DFA, there is no concept of backtracking. For example, in `illiterate`, it will go to the end in one pass and can conclude that the match failed. Then it will retry from `lliterate`, etc. A better example to demonstrate the power of DFA would be `missisipi`, where DFA will mark all `s` as it advances and return the longest match, which is `missis` (theoretically, it can return all matches starting from certain index, but the DFA engine in the wild will return the longest match only).

Comment: Сan it return different results for NFA and DFA? I can't imagine such situations.
It seems like explanation from my quotes is right for DFA engine rather than NFA engine.

Comment: It can be different. It is not very clear from the regex and the example you have above. A backtracking engine has the concept of lazy/greedy quantifier, while DFA engine doesn't have such concept. It is one factor that causes the difference in the result.